# Enabling NTLM Auto login on IIS for fully qualified domain name (FQDN)

Tags: iis, web-applications, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have noticed in our network that when I want to enable users to connect to a Web Application and be automatically logged in, I need to provide them with a URL such as http://server/path/application.aspx.  If I use http://server.domain.com/path/application.aspx, they are prompted to login instead.

I'd like to have both URLs automatically login the users to the Web application, but I'm missing the big picture on how this works (or rather why it doesn't work for both URLs)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide some insight here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see to what security zone in Internet Explorer the FQDN belongs.  Depending on your version of IE (I think anything after IE6), the FQDN must be in the Intranet Zone.

You can find the security zone configuration in Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security if you're unfamiliar with these settings.

Comment: Ahh, of course.  You know, I've seen that before but it's one of things I keep running into and struggling with each time.  Hopefully I'll remember it this time!  Thanks!